# Qml edit variable object or element

Tags: qt, function, variables, block, qml

In my Qt quick application I use c++ to generate a number between 1 and 6, which is then sent with a signal to a QML function. I have six custom `Block` objects or elements (I'm not sure what you call them). The blocks are called `block1` - `6`. I want the the function to something like `block"i".visible = true`, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that. If someone could please help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of declaring 6 individual blocks, declare an array of size six and you can do like this `block[i].visible = true`.

Comment: How do I declare a array of 6 blocks in qml?

Comment: var block = []; It has to be done in Javascript style either as embedded or in a external Javascript file. Now when you want to want to create a "block" (a visual QML element), you need to assign it like this, a dynamic way, block[0] = Qt.createComponent("Block.qml");

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can avoid having to manually create the blocks in javascript:

Assuming all the blocks are children of the same parent, you can access them as `parentsId.children[0]` through `parentsId.children[5]` (or `parentsId.children[n]` through `parentsId.children[n+5]` if the parent has `n` children that come before the boxes).

So something like this would work:

```
Rectangle {
    // ...

    Item {
        id: blocks

        Block {
            id: block1
            // ...
        }
        // ...

        Block {
            id: block6
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ...

    function makeBlockVisible(i) {
        // subtracting 1 from i because you said i is a number between 1 and 6
        // and we need an index between 0 and 5
        blocks.children[i-1].visible = true;
    }
}
```